# How to create a typescript generic type with one optional property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using react with typescript and I have this:

```
interface SomeProps {
  stuff: {
    optionalStuff?: object[];
  }[];
}
```

The only problem with this approach is that if I try to insert any property besides `optionalStuff` inside the `stuff object[]`, it will fail because those properties are not listed.

How can I do something like:

```
interface SomeProps {
  stuff: {
    ACCEPTS_ANY_GENERIC_STUFF_INSIDE: string | number | object | undefined
    optionalStuff?: object[];
  }[];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `SomeProps` generic, so you could specify what other *optional* fields would `stuff` accept. In the example below, `stuff` except `optionalStuff` takes also `foo` field.

```
type SomeProps<T> = {
  stuff: ({
    optionalStuff?: object[];
  } & T)[];
}

const arr: SomeProps<{ foo: string }> = {
  stuff: [{
    optionalStuff: [],
    foo: 'abc'
  }]
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgBQE5zAZwDwBUB8UAvFAN4BQUUmwArgGb0BcUAFBVVRsAJZwB2AQwA2MOowD8LOACMAVhADGwANoBdANyUoAXygAyKLgCU6rTvLlFAmlEGpULeEjQYcpKPThwWNVD34Ac11CEg5qcWYoFXCuMF4BETEGKPUAGm0qLx8oAHJBGUVc7R01ch0gA)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct, but in case you don't know in advance or the type of objects in `stuff` only share the `optionalStuff` array but not the other keys, you could use an index signature.

```js
interface SomeProps {
  stuff: {
    optionalStuff?: object[];
    [key: string]: string | number | object | undefined;
  }[];
}
```

Then you get type checking for `optionalStuff` but the objects can be extended with any other property.